# UWP get text from AutoSuggestBox after Find icon tapped

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I want to get text from AutoSuggestBox after Find icon tapped. Any solutions?

[image]

```
<StackPanel
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0">

                <AutoSuggestBox
                    x:Name="autoSuggestBox"
                    Height="40"
                    Margin="24,44,24,0"
                    Text=""
                    FontSize="32"
                    PlaceholderText="Wyszukaj serial..."
                    QuerySubmitted="autoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
                    SuggestionChosen="autoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"
                    TextChanged="autoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
                    QueryIcon="Find"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

This is XML file.

```
private void autoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            var auto = (AutoSuggestBox)sender;
            var suggestion = suggestions.Where(p => p.StartsWith(auto.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
            auto.ItemsSource = suggestion;
        }
    }

    private void autoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
        {
            autoSuggestBox.Text = args.ChosenSuggestion.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void autoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
    {
        var selectedItem = args.SelectedItem.ToString();
        sender.Text = selectedItem;
    }
```

This is cs file.

After tapped to Find icon i want to get input text and use this string in other function.

Comment: Doesn't `autoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted` get called when you hit the icon?

Comment: No, only after I select suggestion

Comment: No it should get called. Put a breakpoint at `if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)`.

Comment: It works, I added "String selectedText = autoSuggestBox.Text;" in this if and in else statement. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah see my answer it should do what you wanted. You can use `args.QueryText` instead. :)

Comment: I marked it as Correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QuerySubmitted` should be fired. So you are looking for the `else if` in this case.

```
private void autoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null && args.ChosenSuggestion is YourModelItem yourModelItem)
    {
        // When an item is selected...
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.QueryText))
    {
        // When the search box is filled with something...
    }
}
```